# Execute function of a different component

Tags: angular, typescript

I developed a grid with a button that allows me to activate or not a timer.

On the home page, where the grid is, when starting the timer (click on start) the timer starts counting the time.

Through a service I can find out if the timer has been activated or not and change the button status on the navbar component.

How can I pause the timer (execute the pauseTimer function) of the component / home service, but in the navbar component. Basically when a timer is started at home, I intend to pause that same timer, using the stop button but on the navbar component.

Can someone help me?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jizbrd?file=src%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html)

**CODE**

```
  startTimer(userId:string) {
    if (!this.timerForUsers[userId]) {
      this.timerForUsers = {
        ...this.timerForUsers,
        [userId]: {
          currentState: 'start',
          currentTime: 0,
          initialTime: 0,
          startTime: `${Date.now()}`
        }
      };
    }

    const currentUserTimer:TimerForUser = this.timerForUsers[userId];
    clearInterval(currentUserTimer.interval);
    currentUserTimer.startTime = `${Date.now()}`;
    currentUserTimer.initialTime = currentUserTimer.currentTime;

    currentUserTimer.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.timerForUsers = {
        ...this.timerForUsers,
        [userId]: {
          ...this.timerForUsers[userId],
          currentTime: this.timerForUsers[userId].currentTime + 1 
        }
      };
    }, 1000);

    this.userID = userId;
    currentUserTimer.currentState = 'start';
     this.state = currentUserTimer.currentState;


    localStorage.setItem('user_timers', JSON.stringify(this.timerForUsers));
  }

  pauseTimer(userId:string) {
    const currentUserTimer:TimerForUser = this.timerForUsers[userId];

    currentUserTimer.currentState = 'pause';
    this.state = currentUserTimer.currentState;
    clearInterval(currentUserTimer.interval);
    currentUserTimer.interval = null;
    currentUserTimer.initialTime = currentUserTimer.currentTime;
    currentUserTimer.startTime = null;
    localStorage.setItem('user_timers', JSON.stringify(this.timerForUsers));
    currentUserTimer.currentTime = null;
  }

     gettimes() {
    return this.userID;
  }

    getCurrentState() {
    return this.state;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to stop the timer and change the button in nav bar component.
checkout the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygymny?file=src%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.ts)
Hope it helps

I have added

```js
public timerAction:ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

to the **TaskService**

and in HomeComponent

```js
pauseTimer(data) {
     this.taskService.iduser = data.key.ID;
    this.taskService.pauseTimer(data.key.ID);
    this.taskService.timerAction.next(true);// added this
  }
```

in NavbarComponent

```js
constructor(public taskService: TaskService) { 
    this.taskService.currentUserId.subscribe(x => {
      this.userId = x;
      this.startTimer();
    });
    
    // added this, a subscription that listens to change and triggers pausTimer if true.
    this.taskService.timerAction.subscribe(response =>{
      if(response)
        this.pauseTimer();
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me. Yes, when I start the timer at home, I want to see its current status and the current time on the navbar. On the navbar button, When I click STOP, I want the timer to stop (the one on the navbar and the one on the corresponding home page).

Comment: I tested your code but it is not working properly :( can you take a look?

Comment: In navbar.componnet.html, there was an error. If you put this in it already solves an error that appeared.  <span class="timer">{{(taskService.timerForUsers[userId]?.currentTime * 1000) | date:'HH:mm:ss':'UTC'}}</span>    The only problem is that the timer still does not stop when clicked on the navbar.

Comment: @MikeLanders sorry for that, I have updated the code so you can try again.

Comment: You know how I can solve the following problem: I start the timer on the grid (home) and then stop that same timer on the navbar. The problem is that after returning to the home page, the function to pause the timer is always performed ... is there a way to unsubscribe? If you put an alert on the pause2 () function you will see that when you pause a timer on the navbar and then return to the home, you will always receive this alert

Comment: I'm not sure what you want but you can take a look at this [new demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejtnzm?file=src/home/home.component.ts). I'm unsubsrcibing in the ngOnDestroy function in home.component.ts

Comment: Thank you very much. But it continues to do the same, if you put an alert on the pausetimer2 () function to know that the function has been executed, you will see the problem. I start the timer on the home and pause on the navbar, after pausing it on the navbar, whenever I enter the home it always performs this function when in fact it should only be executed once. I don't understand why this happens

Comment: In this function this.timerActionSubscription = this.taskService.timerAction.subscribe (response => {
      if (response) {
        this.pauseTimer2 (response);
        }
        
    })

Is there a way to "destroy" or implement some condition so that it only enters the function when the stop button is clicked on the navbar? It's just that when you stop at the navbar and whenever I return to the home page it always does that, in fact it should only be done once. If I know the resolution, I can open a new question.